# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'plyer.platforms.macosx' even after changing hiddenimports=['plyer.platforms.linux.notification'],

Tags: python, notifications, desktop

I keep getting this error when trying to run the executable created

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "plyer/utils.py", line 93, in _ensure_obj
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'plyer.platforms.macosx'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "notifs.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "plyer/facades/notification.py", line 79, in notify
  File "plyer/facades/notification.py", line 88, in _notify
NotImplementedError: No usable implementation found!
[1227] Failed to execute script 'notifs' due to unhandled exception!
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]
```

when trying to use this **pyinstaller** command

```
pyinstaller --onefile --hidden-import plyer.platforms.linux.notification notifs.py
```

This is happening even after changing in the notifs. spec file

```
hiddenimports=['plyer.platforms.linux.notification'],
```

For reference, this is my entire code block

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import time
from plyer import notification
 
 
if __name__=="__main__":
 
        notification.notify(
            title = "hi",
            message="hello Vasundhara" ,
           
            # displaying time
            timeout=2
)
        # waiting time
        time.sleep(7)
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

based on the error message, have you tried importing the "plyer.platforms.macosx.notification" hidden import?

as stated here:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'plyer.platforms.macosx'`

the error message is not asking for a linux import which is what you seem to be trying to fix but is instead asking for macosx.

try running: `pyinstaller --onefile --hidden-import plyer.platforms.macosx.notification notifs.py`

i'm not sure if this will work as i don't personally have a mac to test this on, but i hope this helps